# Trouble Connecting Digital Ocean to Laravel Application

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, stripe-payments, digital-ocean

I am having trouble connecting my laravel project to digital ocean. I am using ubuntu LAMP 16.04 to connect my project but i am getting a error telling me that says the ext-curl is missing but i already installed ext-curl by running

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
sudo mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
```

I know the problem has something to do with stripe but not sure of a soultion .

---

```
root@lamp-512mb-nyc3-01:/var/www/pengiun# composer install
Do not run Composer as root/super user! See https://getcomposer.org/root for details
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested PHP extension ext-curl * is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's curl extension.
  Problem 2
    - Installation request for stripe/stripe-php v5.6.0 -> satisfiable by stripe/stripe-php[v5.6.0].
    - stripe/stripe-php v5.6.0 requires ext-curl * -> the requested PHP extension curl is missing from your system.

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-apcu.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `php curl` extension using the below code. `Composer` is only a dependency manager for PHP. For more information on composer, visit https://getcomposer.org/doc/00-intro.md

`sudo apt-get install php7.0-curl`